# Conditions on Bessel function identities with opposite order sign

Tags: complex-analysis, bessel-functions

As regards modified Bessel function of the [first](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and [second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html), in some cases the following relations hold:

$$I_{-n} (x) = I_{n} (x)\\
K_{-n} (x) = K_{n} (x)$$

- Under what conditions on $n$ these relations are true?
- Is there a site/document showing them?

---

My attempt: only as regards $K_{n} (x)$, I considered its [integral definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1):

$$K_{n} (x) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x \cosh t} \cosh (\alpha t) \mathrm{d}t, \ \mathrm{Re[x]} > 0$$

where trivially $\cosh(\alpha t) = \cosh(- \alpha t)$, being hyperbolic cosine an even function.

---

I am struggling to find a homogeneous source for all these types of functions. [This one](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.4) and [this one](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27) don't mention at all the fact that $n$ should be integer or not. [This one](http://nlpc.stanford.edu/nleht/Science/reference/bessel.pdf) (page 19) shows the relation, but nothing is mentioned about $n$.

As regards the Bessel functions of the [first](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and [second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html):

$$J_{-n} (x) = (-1)^{n} J_{n} (x)\\
N_{-n} (x) = (-1)^{n} N_{n} (x)$$

the relations hold only for integer $n$, as stated in Wikipedia, respectively for [$J_{n} (x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1) and [$N_{n} (x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_second_kind:_Y%CE%B1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27) shows that:

$$I_{-n} (x) = I_n (x)$$

only if $n$ is an integer. More in general, instead

$$I_{-\nu} (x) = I_{\nu} (x) + \frac{2}{\pi} \sin(\nu \pi) K_{\nu} (x)$$

The second relation has no limitations. It is valid for any $\nu$, not only the integer ones:

$$K_{-\nu} (x) = K_{\nu} (x)$$

In fact:

$$K_{\nu} (x) = \pi \frac{I_{-\nu} (x) - I_{\nu} (x)}{2 \sin(\pi \nu)}$$

and

$$K_{-\nu} (x) = \pi \frac{I_{\nu} (x) - I_{-\nu} (x)}{- 2 \sin(\pi \nu)} = \pi \frac{I_{-\nu} (x) - I_{\nu} (x)}{ 2 \sin(\pi \nu)} = K_{\nu} (x)$$